# ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.multioutput'

Tags: scikit-learn

when I import MultiOutputRegressor with `from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor`,I got a `ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.multioutput'`.
Does anyone know how to deal with it? thank you!

Comment: Are you able to import sklearn? Which version of sklearn are you using?

Comment: The version is 0.17.1,thank you for your reply.

Comment: The module "multioutput" is not present in 0.17. Please update to latest version of scikit

Comment: OK!Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error which I removed by updating `sklearn` to the latest version (0.18) with the following `pip` command:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```